# Chaining queries in mongoose

Tags: mongoose, hook, middleware

Please check the below mongoose code in nodejs.

```
reviewSchema.pre(/^findOneAnd/, async function(next) {
      this.review = await this.findOne();
      next();
    });
    reviewSchema.post(/^findOneAnd/, async function(next) {
      await this.review.constructor.calcSaveAverage(this.review.tourRef);
    });
```

What i am trying to do is to fetch certain details from a given document before it is deleted. The document is deleted using the findOneAndDelete() query method. In the pre-findhook the query gets modified and the document is saved as the review property on the query. Here, calcSaveAverage is an instance method on the model.

What i am unable to understand is that since this.findOne() changes the query how will the delete operation be performed. I read this code in an online tutorial and it is working just as intended. But i am not able to understand...